# C# Coded UI Test never selects correct item in grid

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am having a problem getting a coded UI test to select the correct item in a grid. I record the whole thing slowly and save the recording. While I am recording, one of the tasks it to select item D in a grid.

When I play back the recorded test, it selects item A or sometimes item B when it gets to the grid. This ends up throwing the whole test off.

Why is this happening? Is the test not recording properly? Is there anything that can be done to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: what values are you searching with? please include some code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to following reasons:

1. While you record, the row place is different with respect to play back;
2. It always identify with the dynamic row ID and it will try to search for the same.

Solution: you can use descriptive way of coding in order to handle GRID.
Identify the grid and get the row with respect to unique text in that row and do the necessary action.